# PHP equivalent for java function shown

Tags: java, php, android

I make php script to interact with an api which developer of it design for android. but developer of this Api he no publish it he only have andriod app examples..so I am at a task for convert this java to work with php. everything is easy quickly for me since it mainly be post and parse json...I only have problem with password encode code which I fail to make by php. I try just base64_encode  but it no work if I try. here is java code. my java very small, I need translate for php

```
import android.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

public final class c
{

private Cipher a;
private Cipher b;
private final byte c[] = {
    -87, -101, -56, 50, 86, 53, -29, 3
};

public c(String s)
{
    PBEKeySpec pbekeyspec = new PBEKeySpec(s.toCharArray(), c, 20);
    try
    {
        SecretKey secretkey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(pbekeyspec);
        a = Cipher.getInstance(secretkey.getAlgorithm());
        b = Cipher.getInstance(secretkey.getAlgorithm());
        PBEParameterSpec pbeparameterspec = new PBEParameterSpec(c, 20);
        a.init(1, secretkey, pbeparameterspec);
        b.init(2, secretkey, pbeparameterspec);
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return;
    }
  }

  public final String a(String s)
  {
    String s1;
    try
    {
        s1 = Base64.encodeToString(a.doFinal(s.getBytes()), 0);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return s1;
  }
}
```

im interested understanding this function of  public final String a(String s)

Answer (score 0):

for decode base64 :

```
<?php
$str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
echo base64_decode($str);
?>
```

encode :

```
<?php
$str = 'This is an encoded string';
echo base64_encode($str);
?>
```

reference :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: its for password encryption and require mcrypt